# What is this matrix decomposition called and does it exist always? - II

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, nonnegative-matrices, decomposition-theorem

Given a rank $2r$ matrix $M\in\Bbb Q_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$ can we find two matrices $M_+\in\Bbb Q_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$ and $M_-\in\Bbb Q_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$ each of rank at most $r$ such that $M=M_+-M_-$ holds?

Variant of [What is this matrix decomposition called and does it exist always?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290126/what-is-this-matrix-decomposition-called-and-does-it-exist-always) and $M$ is non-negative here and so the counter example there does not work.